# Word VBA script

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am looking for word VBA script to hide table cell with grey background.
I have files which have lots of table, in that there are some cells with background color, I need to hide the content of this cells... can anyone help me out?

Comment: It would help if you had some code to work from. Finding shaded cells can be a problem. See this article which might help http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macword/find-and-change-on-table-cell-shading/5eab329e-55f0-4f00-b477-a5bc05a0faee   This demonstrates how to change the cell shading. Instead of this you could change the text colour to be the same as the background.

Answer (score 0):

```
selection.homekey wdstory 
    With Selection.find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Highlight = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        Do While .Execute = True
            If selection.range.HighlightColorIndex = wdgray25 and Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) = False Then
                Selection.RANGE.font.Hidden = True
                ''Selection.RANGE.font.ColorIndex = wdWhite   ''to hide the text content
                ''Selection.RANGE.HighlightColorIndex = wdAuto ''to remove the highlight
            End If
            selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
```